# Hexadecimal to float converter

Tags: arithmetic

I have a hexadecimal to float converter in the form of a code by I am unable to understand as to how did they carry out the conversion.

For Ex: If I have a hexadecimal number as : 11433333;
    the answer I get from that function is: 145.200.

I tried several methods of conversion like these:

http://www.cs.uaf.edu/~cs301/notes/Chapter4/node13.html

http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/32bit.html

There is something to do with little endian and big endian, but I am not familiar with that. None of these are giving me the output as 145.200. Could anyone explain me a way out of this please?

Cheers in advance.

Comment: Which is it, 145.200 or 145.2200? While you're at it, please check whether there's a typo in the hexadecimal number.

Comment: 145.2200 is a float value that is generated as an output from the function. There is no typo, everything is fine. I get float values from other hexadecimal input as well.

Comment: It's bad enough that there's an obvious typo in your question. I don't see why anyone should bother spending time on answering your question if you don't even take the time to check it after the typo has been pointed out to you.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It is 145.200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mystery is resolved when you do the conversion [the other way around](http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/Decimal.html): the IEEE representation of 145.2 is 43 11 33 33<sub>16</sub>. So some part of your code is getting the byte order mixed up.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was just going through that. Glad you told me earlier. It saved me a bunch of calculations. :)

Cheers.

Comment: IIRC, that's exactly the difference between "little endian" and "big endian".  They will switch the order of bytes within a word.